# Swap ctrl-tab and alt-tab using XKB

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I would like to swap the behaviors of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (and also swap the behaviors of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>), while keeping the rest of `Ctrl-` and `Alt-` shortcuts unchanged (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is still `copy`).

Can I do it using xkb on Linux?

Comment: I don't think you can lie about modifiers, even with XKB. Can't you swap the keyboard shortcuts around?

Comment: I tried to swap the shortcuts on Ubuntu shortcut setting, but no effect..

Comment: Btw, I can successfully map Alt-Tab to Ctrl-Tab using XKB with "level3(lalt_switch)", but not Ctrl-Tab to Alt-Tab yet..

Comment: Ah, so you should be able to do what you want by defining a different set of levels for the `<TAB>` key. Look in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/level3` for inspiration.